# How to add an tooltip to menu Google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, tooltip

Who knows how i can add an tooltip to an menu item of an self added menu in google spreadsheet?

All I can find about an Add menu is [This](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu)

So to add an menu item i write this:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
       .createMenu('My Menu')
       .addItem('My Menu Item', 'myFunction')
       .addSeparator()
       .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Submenu')
           .addItem('One Submenu Item', 'mySecondFunction')
           .addItem('Another Submenu Item', 'myThirdFunction'))
       .addToUi();
```

How can i Add an tooltip to the "My Menu Item"?

Thanks for your help, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

At this time it's not possible to add a tooltip to custom menus.

## Explanation

The document that your refer is the official documentation. AFAIK there isn't any other class and method that could help.

It's worth to say that features requests should be posted on [Google Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Comment: I created [this ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243778591) - let's hope there is any work in progress...